# Run Subprocess on Server Between Page Loads on Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, subprocess

I'm very new to python and Django and I'm trying to figure out the correct way to do something within Django. I have a Django app half completed, but I'm not sure how to run the subprocess in between.

I have a python script that takes 3 variables and inserts them into a subprocess that runs a single command on OpenSSL.  This is a simplified version of this python script:

```
issuer = "path/to/file"
serial = "hex number goes here"
URL = "http URL here"

arequest = subprocess.check_output "openssl", "ocsp", "-nonce", "-noverify", "-issuer", issuer, "-serial", serial, "-url", URL])

print(arequest)
```

This script that I have works.  What I'm aiming to do is to have `subprocess.check_output` run in Django between a page load, such that:

1. Page 1 accepts field inputs for the variables and the user clicks
   submit.
2. The variable field data is input into the `subprocess.check_output` command and this is run on the server to give `arequest`.
3. Page 2 displays the results of `arequest` in a text field.

I also don't want anything stored within the database other than information outside the scope of this question.  I know that in order to do this, I will need to get information using either GET or POST but I'm not sure of the 'theory' behind the best approach to make this work.  Can someone help push me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't have it "between pages", but the script can certainly accept data in a POST request and display the result in the response. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: This is where I'm confused.
1) I have 2 functions in my views.py.  I have "index" which defines the code and variables for the "index.html" page (where the submit button is) and I have "results" which defines the code and variable for the "results.html" page. Where do I insert the code to reference the python script?
2) How do I reference the python script?
3) How do I pass the data from POST into the python script and then back again?

I think I'm just confused on where exactly this code needs to happen so that it runs the command on the server and returns the data that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button on your index page should post a form to the results view. That view then runs the script and passes the results to the results.html template.

Comment: I just did some messing around and here is where I'm at: I have three fields on the index page and I've created variables on the results based on these fields.  I have each variable showing up in a `<textarea>` based on the POST data and it works! I'm only doing this to prove that I am getting the correct data.  Now I just need to pass these variables to the script.  I'm guessing that in my results view, I specify these variables and then import the script and run it using them?  Once I do that, I get the answer from the script and publish that variable?

Comment: I figured it out with your help. In my views.py I included `from subprocess import *` and then on the results function, I added `arequest = check_output(cmd code goes here)`.  I then created `result = str(arequest, "utf-8")` and published the result to my render.  It works! Thank you for all of your help!